# Jacoco report is not considering Cucumber tests in Maven

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, jacoco

Written some cucumber tests and used Jacoco plugin to generate code coverage report. I am using maven for build. While doing 'mvn test' cucumber tests are being executed after that Jacoco is being executed to generate the report. However the code coverage is showing 0% for the class which is being used in tests. It looks like the Jacoco is not considering the cucumber tests for code coverage. Below is the pom.xml.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.6.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>src/test/java/</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>

                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes><include>**/libs/*</include></excludes>
                        <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>target/my-reports</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
```

I would be really thankful if somebody could help me out here. I assume - missing some configuration for jacoco.

Comment: Does cucumber support JUnit Jupiter? If I correctly remember it does not...

Comment: You don't need both JUnit and TestNG. You also don't need both Junit Jupiter Engine and Junit47. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to learn how to create minimal examples of your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new to cucumber tests frame work.  I removed the TestNG and removed the Junit Jupiter Engine. But still the code coverage is not considering the cucumber tests.

Comment: However I noticed while running 'mvn test' , 2 times tests are getting executed in console . 
I am assuming the second test run is showing "Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0", after that it is generating jacoco report. As the second run is showing 0 test run that may be the reason jacoco report is showing 0 percentage code coverage for  the java class which is being used in cucumber tests.